# in vue 3.3 alpha 4 props destructure

Tags: vuejs3, vue-props

I am trying vue 3.3.0 alpha-4 new feature but there is one problem. after destructure of props, normally it should keep their reactivity. but only field keep it.

```
const {
  field,
  dialog,
} = defineProps<{
  field: {name: string, value: string},
  dialog: boolean
}>()

onMounted((): void => {
  nextTick(async (): Promise<void> => {
    dialog = false // not working
    field.name = "data" // works
    console.log(field, dialog)
  })
})
```

errors says for dialog

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, the props are read-only, so the way you are trying to change the `dialog` value is per se wrong.

Second, there is the [Reactive Props Destructure](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#reactive-props-destructure) part of the Vue Docs, describing exactly what you are observing:

> 1. Similar to .value, you need to always access props as props.x in order
>    to retain reactivity. This means **you cannot destructure** `defineProps`
>    **because the resulting destructured variables are not reactive** and will
>    not update.

And, at the end.

This has nothing to do with the Vue Version `3.3.0-alpha.4`.
You can try the [SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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) and switch the Vue version to see, that the props destructuring behave the same, independently from the version you choose.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to state, that you can also use [`toRefs()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#torefs), to destruct your props preserving reactivity.

```
 const props = defineProps<{
    field: {name: string, value: string},
    dialog: boolean }>()

 const { field, dialog } = toRefs(props)
```

And then use `dialog.value` to access the value. But they still remain readonly and you will get the Vue Warning, if you try to change the value.

> [Vue warn] Set operation on key "dialog" failed: target is
> readonly.[object Object]

Check this [SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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)

Comment: Wrong, this has everything to do with the Vue version. Since 3.3 reactive props destructuring can be used, it just needs to be activated explicitly because it is opt-in only for now. Your answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

**Since Vue.js 3.3**,

Your initial code should work if you re using vite and opt in for the destructureProps: true configuration (see vite config below).
This option enables prop destructuring and the assignment of default values to props inside your  block.

Note: This was originally part of the RFC Reactivity Transform (which is now deprecated) but the destructuring props has been keep/extracted from RFC because it has several advantages.

```js
//vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({  
  plugins: [
    vue({
      script: {
        propsDestructure: true,
      }
    })
  ]
})
```

source: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/vue-js-3-how-to-destructure-props-in-composition-api#destructurevuepropswithvite

Et voilà :) !

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the other one is incorrect and doesn't mention this needs to be activated in the vite config.